# Responsive parallax jumbotron not working with media queries

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I am using a `.bg` class, coupled with some jquery to create a parallax scroll effect on a `jumbotron`. It works as planned on larger screens, however the height does not adjust for smaller devices. I have put in the following media query to resize the `.bg` to `height: 350px` on devices with `max-width: 768px`. However on doing this the `.bg` element becomes fixed to the page so that all other contents overlay it upon scrolling and the parallax effect is lost.

I have researched SO and have been unable to find a similar query, so if there is any feedback it would be much appreciated.

HTML:-

```
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron_about">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>A brief<br>
            history of me</h1>
            <h5>Read on and learn</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.bg {
background-size: cover!important;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 350px!important;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index: -1;
}

#jumbotron_about {
height: 350px!important;
background:transparent;
}
}
```

[Here is a link to my webpage](http://www.jonhowlett.uk/about.html)

Many thanks
Jon

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your site there are three properties setting the height. In your media query, you need to include heights for `.bg`, `#jumbotron_about` and `.jumbotron`.

Most importantly, `#jumbotron_about` is not in your media query in your sites' CSS like it is in your example above which I think is where the problem lies.

So

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {    
.jumbotron, #jumbotron_about, .bg {
    height: 380px;
  }
...
}
```